# Twig javascript in included child

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a question regarding adding javascript to child elements. How do you do that?

I have this setup:

**base.html.twig:**

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}

{% block script %}
{% endblock script %}
```

**index.html.twig:**

```
{% extends base.html.twig %}

{% include intro.html.twig %}

{% block content %} 
<html></html>
{% endblock content %}

{% block script %}
<script></script>
{% endblock script %}
```

**intro.html.twig:**

```
{% block script %}
<script></script>
{% endblock script %}
```

I want to add more javascript files into the intro.html.twig file, but it doesn't append it to the script block in index.html.twig.

All help appreciated!

**UPDATE**
I want to send some parameters with `intro.html.twig`:

```
{% extends 'intro.html.twig' with {
'title': 'title',
'type': 'test',
} %}
```

is this possible using extends, or can I only use `with` with include?

Comment: why don't you define your parameters in controller, then you can access it from parent and child template.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>index.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends intro.html.twig %}

{% block content %} 
    <html></html>
{% endblock content %}

{% block script %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script></script>
{% endblock script %}
```

<kbd>intro.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends base.html.twig %}

{% block script %}
    <script></script>
{% endblock script %}
```

Comment: Hi Arcv, I also have javascript files in index.html.twig, so that solution won't do :/

Comment: Sure it does. You need to add another `parent()`-call. [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/lvwta6)

Comment: Ok I see :) There is only one problem: how do I extend the intro.html.twig template with parameters. see edited answer.

Comment: sorry, here you go :)